# woocommerce- How to only show subcategories on shop page?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce, product

Edit:Managed to limit subcategories to shop page by wrapping the code inside the function in `if(is_shop())`.NOw my shop page has multiple print outs of all the subcategories, I want to limit it to ONE Print of all the categories possibly paginated.

I am trying to show Subcategories(or child categories)only on the shop page then once a subcategory is selected show the products within. My code below shows the subcategories on the main shop page but once a subcategory is selected it still shows all subcategories above the products. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
    function Only_show_Subcategories($args = array()){

   $terms = get_terms( array(
   'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
   'hide_empty' => true,
   ) );
     if($terms){

         echo '<ul class = "products product-grid gutters row clearfix columns-3">';

            foreach ($terms as $term){

                if($term->parent > 0){

                echo '<li class="product-category product col-sm-4 first product-category product item-animated">';
                echo'<a href="'. esc_url( get_term_link( $term)). '"class="'.$term->slug.'">';

                  woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail( $term);

                echo '</a>';
                  echo '<h2>';
                    echo'<a href="'. esc_url( get_term_link( $term)). '"class= product-details"'.$term->slug.'">';
                         echo $term->name;
                               echo '</a>';
                         echo '</h2>';
                         echo '</li>';

                }
            }
        echo '</ul>';
     }

 }
 add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop','Only_show_Subcategories', 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well and I solved it with a work around.  I added the plugin called "Widgets On Pages" then I went to my widgets, added the woocommerce product categroies to it and selected to only show sub categories. Then I made a new page and added the shortcode in it for the widgets on pages that I created and set my woocommerce shop page to that page.  Problem solved.